# Rename the label on a menu location which is already defined?

Tags: menus

I have a menu location defined by a theme, I'd like to change the label from Header Menu to something else (but keeping all it's other settings as is), I can't find any suitable filters to do this within WordPress - is this possible?

[image: Menu location]

Comment: The label is defined by the theme, not by WordPress.

Comment: Yes, the label is defined by the theme with no filter, therefore the question is whether there are any hooks/filters within WordPress which reads those definitions and to then manipulate the label at that point to give the desired result. @MaxYudin

Comment: There's no hook for registered menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right there is no filter for this, you would have to hack the global instead, in this case `$_wp_registered_nav_menus`:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_menu_location_label');
function custom_menu_location_label() {
    global $_wp_registered_nav_menus;
    $find = __('Header Menu'); $replace = __('Something Else');
    foreach ($_wp_registered_nav_menus as $location => $description) {
        if ($find == $description) {
            $_wp_registered_nav_menus[$location] = $replace;
        }
    }
}
```